# Redirect bots to server side rendering of Anguar site

Tags: seo, google-search, angular

We have written an Angular web application, it is an online catalog of items. We would like Google and the other search engines to index it. The urls have this format: `/catalog?item=sku`, where sku could be any product my company sells.

After trying without success server side rendering, we decided to use roast.io, a service that takes care of the pre-rendering. What we would like to achieve is to serve our application from our Azure content delivery network and redirect to roast.io only the request that comes from bots. The redirect works, but google still hasn't index our website (since more than one month). Is anyone using the same approach and as a suggestion or an alternative?

Comment: If you redirect Googlebot, Googlebot will index the URL to which it was redirected and not the original URL.     If you want good SEO, I'd recommend switching to a framework that doesn't require JavaScript for rendering.